# Why does SQL ALTER TABLE Firmen ADD COLUMN Firma nvarchar(50) NOT NULL; not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have to do a task for school and I can't get it to work.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio. I have a table `Firmen` and I would like to add a column `Firma` to it, defined as a text with max length of 50 characters.

To my understanding, the syntax to do this is

```sql
USE Schueler;

ALTER TABLE Firmen 
    ADD COLUMN Firma nvarchar(50) NOT NULL;
```

But I get this error

> Falsche Syntax in der Nähe des COLUMN-Schlüsselworts.

Translating into

> Wrong Syntax near COLUMN keyword

I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A new column can't be NOT NULL without having a default value.

Comment: It can when the table is empty. The error showing is incorrect syntax.

Comment: Step 1 would be to **consult the [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)** on `ALTER TABLE` -..... it shows you should use `ALTER TABLE (table) ADD (column name) ` - no `COLUMN` keyword .....

Comment: I wish they would just make that an optional keyword here. It would then be consistent with `ALTER COLUMN` and `DROP COLUMN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the COLUMN keyword. it should be:

```
ALTER TABLE Firmen ADD Firma nvarchar(50) NOT NULL;
```

**Edit**

As jarlh mentioned. When the table already has data you have to make the column NULLABLE, use a default value, or make it NULLABLE, fill it and ALTER it again to make it not NULLABLE.

Comment: You would be better off `DROP`ing the `CONSTRAINT` afterwards than doing an `UPDATE` on the *entire* table. Especially on Enterprise.

Comment: I think that depends on the situation. Dropping the constraint will enable the column to have NULL values. Perhaps that is not wanted. Or am I understanding your comment wrong?

Comment: If the column is defined as `NOT NULL` it can't have `NULL` values, @Peter. A `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` doesn't stop a column having a `NULL` value if it's defined as `NULL`.

Comment: Ah, when rereading my edit, it was a bit unclear indeed.
What I ment, we have 3 options, 1 make nullable, 2 keep not null, but add a default value or 3, make with nullable, add data, make not nullable.

Comment: Where 1 and 2 are only meta data, 3 can be an intensive update

Comment: Yes, but if you `ADD` the column *with* a `DEFAULT` value, and then `DROP` the `CONSTRAINT` then it's meta data only (on enterprise), regardless of if the column is defined as `NULL`able or not.

Comment: Ah, understand you now, thanks! :)